# im facing this error in kubernetes using minikube

Tags: kubernetes

I tried to deploy nginx server using kubernetes. I was able to create deployment and thn create service. But when i gave the curl command im facing an error. Im not able to curl and open nginx webpage in browser.
Below are the commands i used and error i got.

```
kubectl get pods

NAME                                READY   STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
curl                                1/1     Running             8          15d
curl-deployment-646445496f-59fs9    1/1     Running             7          15d
hello-5d448ffc76-cwzcl              1/1     Running             13         23d
hello-node-7567d9fdc9-ffdkx         1/1     Running             8          20d
my-nginx-5b6fb7fb46-bdzdq           0/1     ContainerCreating   0          15d
mytestwebapp                        1/1     Running             10         21d
nginx-6799fc88d8-w76cb              1/1     Running             5          13d
nginx-deployment-66b6c48dd5-9mkh8   1/1     Running             12         23d
nginx-test-795d659f45-d9shx         1/1     Running             4          13d
rss-site-7b6794856f-9586w           2/2     Running             40         15d
rss-site-7b6794856f-z59vn           2/2     Running             78         21d
jit@jit-Vostro-15-3568:~$ kubectl logs webserver
Error from server (NotFound): pods "webserver" not found


jit@jit-Vostro-15-3568:~$ kubectl get svc


NAME         TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                        AGE
hello-node   LoadBalancer   10.104.134.171   <pending>     8080:31733/TCP                 13d
kubernetes   ClusterIP      10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP                        23d
my-nginx     NodePort       10.103.114.92    <none>        8080:32563/TCP,443:32397/TCP   15d
nginx        NodePort       10.110.113.60    <none>        80:30985/TCP                   13d
nginx-test   NodePort       10.109.16.192    <none>        8080:31913/TCP                 13d


jit@jit-Vostro-15-3568:~$ curl kube-worker-1:30985


curl: (6) Could not resolve host: kube-worker-1
```

Comment: The error asks to check your network connection. Add a domain and check that the host is routable from where you tried this. Please describe own efforts how you tried to solve the problem when asking a question.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see you have pod called `nginx`, that indicates that you have had `nginx` server already deployed in pod on your cluster.  You don't have pod called `webserver` that's why you're getting

```
Error from server (NotFound): pods "webserver" not found  error.
```

Also to access nginx service try to pass curl it via `ip:port`:

```
$ curl 10.110.113.60:30985
```

If you point a web browser to [http://IP_OF_NODE:ASSIGNED_PORT](https://www.techrepublic.com/) (where IP_OF_NODE is an IP address of one of your nodes and ASSIGNED_PORT is the port assigned during the create service command), you should see the NGINX Welcome page!

Take a look: [nginx-app-kubernetes](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-deploy-nginx-on-a-kubernetes-cluster/).

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above scenario locally.

do a `kubectl describe svc <svc-name>`
check whether it have any end-points.
probably it doesn't have any endpoints